# Singleton : what is better choice?

Tags: java, singleton

**Method 1**

```
 public static synchronized Database getInstance(){
   if(INSTANCE == null){
     INSTANCE = new Database();
   }
   return INSTANCE;
}
```

**Method 2**

```
private static final Database INSTANCE = new Database();
    public static Database getInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }
```

Which is the better choice ?

Comment: You should tag a programming language